# z label scatter plot

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I've a problem in plotting a 3D scatter plot.
I can't understand why the z label is distorced

can you help me?

```
scatter3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3),50,index_color,'filled')

xlabel('1$^{st}$ component','Interpreter','LaTex','FontSize',14);
ylabel('2$^{nd}$ component','Interpreter','LaTex','FontSize',14);
zlabel('3$^{rd}$ component','Interpreter','LaTex','FontSize',14);
```

I'm using ubuntu and matlab R2012b

[image]

Comment: It doesn't happen on my system (Matlab R2010Rb on Windows Vista 32 bits).

Comment: For me it happens on all the vertical labels... (also in 2D plots)

Comment: Could be a graphics card incompatibility. Try changing the renderer, e.g. `set(gcf,'renderer','zbuffer')`

Comment: no, it doesn't solve the problem...thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had spotty luck with the LaTeX interpreter (in Windows). Try the TeX interpreter instead:

```
xlabel('1^{st} component','Interpreter','tex','FontSize',14);
ylabel('2^{nd} component','Interpreter','tex','FontSize',14);
zlabel('3^{rd} component','Interpreter','tex','FontSize',14);
```